# Insert data frm List<String[]> to List<String> and Map<Striing,Striing>

Tags: java, hashmap

After reading data from a CSV file, I have it stored in List.

```
List <String>listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
Map<String,String>listDataChild = new HashMap<String, String>();

List<String[]> termDefinition = csv.read();
```

Then I itirate over the list and want to store the data. As it is written now, I take the correct keys, but not the values:

```
for (String[] term : termDefinition) {
    listDataHeader.add(term[0]);
    listDataChild.put(term[0], term[1]);
}
```

May you help me? Thanks!

EDIT:
I need to fill data in ExpandavbleListVew. The listdataHeader is the main topic, the listdataChild is the subitem. There are only 2 columns in the CSV, in the format term-definition. At the moment, main topics (from the listDataheader) are stored correctly. After correcting the loop (see above), I have for each main item the definition appearing as many times as the size of the loop (10 in the case).

Here is the expandableListView class:

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private List<String> listDataHeader; // header titles
    // child data in format of header title, child title
    private Map<String, String> listDataChild;

    public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
                                 Map<String, String> listChildData) {
        this.context = context;
        this.listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
        this.listDataChild = listChildData;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
        return this.listDataChild.get(this.listDataHeader.get(groupPosition));
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                             boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null);
        }

        TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.itemList);

        txtListChild.setText(childText);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return this.listDataChild.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return this.listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return this.listDataHeader.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                             View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.header, null);
        }

        TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.headerList);
        lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you share more details about this? For example: Sample input data, expected output data and your current output.

Comment: Have a look above, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the point of the `listDataHeader` `List`. Using it causes you to put the same key (`listDataHeader.get(0)`) over and over again in the `Map`.

Since you only have 2 columns in each row of the CSV, all you need is :

```
for (String[] term : termDefinition) {
    listDataChild.put(term[0], term[1]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I've dded some more details above, will try  to examine what causes the problem now.